# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6739 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] Node.js/redis

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to connect to redis using the [`redis`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) package with the following code:

```js
const redis = require('redis')

const client = redis.createClient({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 6739
  })
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```sh
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6739
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6739
}
```

However, I have redis up and running, when I check its status using `sudo systemctl status redis` I get:

```sh
● redis-server.service - LSB: redis-server - Persistent key-value db
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/redis-server; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2021-11-04 17:08:10 UTC; 44min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 63842 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/redis-server start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 04 17:08:10 acecom-instance-3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: redis-server - Persistent key-value db...
Nov 04 17:08:10 acecom-instance-3 systemd[1]: Started LSB: redis-server - Persistent key-value db.
```

When I try to use `redis-cli ping` I get `PONG`. So everything looks to be correct. I also allow connections through `ufw`, this is the output if I run `sudo ufw status numbered`:

```sh
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 3000:5000/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 6739                       ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 6] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 7] 80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 8] 443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 9] 3000:5000/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[10] 6739 (v6)                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

I followed this [docs](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart), some others details you may consider important:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS aarch64
Node: v16.13.0
pm2: v5.1.2
redis: v3.1.2
```

Comment: What does `lsof -i :6739` print?

Comment: Nothing, is it supposed to show something?

Comment: It should listend the process that uses the port 6739. Therefore your redis server (if its really running) does not use the port 6739 which would explain your node.js error message. Post your redis config. (in your systemctl output it says "exited" and not "running") Is the dot (in the systemctl output) green/red or white? I highly doubt that redis is running, the ufw output is just a firewal rule and has nothing to do if the port is used by a program or not. Try a simple netcat/telnet `telnet 127.0.0.1 6739`

Comment: You were right, I was pointing to a wrong port, I was able to find what was the correct port by using `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`, thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc commented, my problem was that I was pointing to the wrong port, the correct port was 6379, not 6739. I could found what port redis was using by running `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`